# x86_64 Assembly: effects of the interrupt flag and TPR register

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, interrupt, windows-kernel

I've been familiar with both the task priority register `cr8` (IRQL on Windows), and of course I know how we can enable and disable interrupts using `cli` and `sti`. However, I have a few questions regarding the two.

First, does clearing the interrupt flag `cli` "override" the current value stored in the TPR? For example: the TPR is `PASSIVE_LEVEL (0)`. If interrupts are disabled, does the value in the TPR not matter anymore? Second: I was reading this from Wikipedia:

> Loading TPR with 0 enables all external interrupts. Loading TPR with 15 (1111b) disables all external interrupts.

Does this mean setting the TPR to `0xF` `KzRaiseIrql(HIGH_LEVEL)` is equivalent to `cli`? What happens if my TPR is `0xF` and the interrupt flag is cleared? What if the interrupt flag is enabled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two are completely independent, and it works exactly as you’d expect.

If IF is 0, it doesn’t matter what TPR is. If TPR is 0xF, it doesn’t matter what IF is.
In either case, all interrupts are masked.

Comment: By the way, the two registers are implemented in different places. IF is implemented in the core, and TPR is implemented in the local APIC. If TPR = 0xF, the APIC won’t assert an interrupt to the core. If TPR < 0xF, the APIC will assert an interrupt to the core (if there is one pending with priority greater than TPR), but the core won’t acknowledge the interrupt if IF is 0.

Comment: Also, EXTINT (if enabled) is masked by IF=0 but not by TPR=0xF

Comment: What exactly is EXTINT? Something from the APIC? @PaoloBonzini

Comment: It's a setting for the delivery mode field in the APIC's LINT registers. If LINT0's delivery mode is set to EXTINT. interrupts from the legacy 8259 interrupt controller are delivered to CPU 0 in a backwards compatible way.